# Stylesheets break when rewriting a URL like profile/foo to profile.php?username=foo

Tags: url-rewriting

I have this code in an `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1
```

My CSS stylesheet is working on all pages, except those matching the last rule (for the profile):

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1
```

For example, when I type `www.mydomain.com/register`, the stylesheet is working.
But when I type `www.mydomain.com/profile/username`, the stylesheet doesn't work.

My stylesheets and other auxiliary files are in separate folders: `css/`, `images/`, `js/`, etc.

What can i do? Please help :D

---

Edit: I have a header and a footer like this: `includes/header.php`, `includes/footer.php`. In the file `header.php` is the PHP code:

```
<?php include 'head.php'; ?>
```

In this `head.php` is the meta tag for CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen-site.css">
```

Here's a screenshot of the folder structure: http://shrani.si/f/3z/13T/1OKC8ZJc/site.png

Comment: I don't see why it would. You have no logic handling that condition.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Well, it looks like it would get rewritten to `/user/username.php`, but the problem is the 2nd rule catches everything, resulting in `/profile.php?username=/user/username.php`

Comment: if you use relative URLs for images/css/javascript you can set the `base` meta tag in your html, then it will not conflict with your .htaccess file

Comment: well actually i have a header and a footer like this:
includes/header.php,
includes/footer.php.

In the file header.php is a php code:
<?php
include 'head.php';
?>

In this head.php is the meta tag for css:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen-site.css">

Your suggestions, what should i do now?

Screen of folder structure: http://shrani.si/f/3z/13T/1OKC8ZJc/site.png

Comment: sorry: this is my actually code:

`Options +FollowSymLinks`
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`
`RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create a variable in a config.php file with your base url:

```
$base_url = "http://www.yourdomain.com/";
```

Then in your header file:

```
<link href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>css/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that those are all *internal* rewrites.  So, even though your webserver is sending data from `/profile.php?username=whatever`, the browser still thinks it's receiving a page from `http://www.mydomain.com/profile/whatever`.

Thus, when it sees a relative URL like `css/screen-site.css`, it resolves it to `http://www.mydomain.com/profile/css/screen-site.css`, which does not exist.

I can think of at least three different ways to solve the problem:

1. The simplest and probably best solution would be to prepend a `/` to your links, so that they look like `/css/screen-site.css`.  The slash makes the browser treat the URL paths as relative to the root directory of your site, rather than (what it believes to be) the current directory.
2. Alternatively, you could include a `base` tag in your HTML `head` section, as slash197 suggests, something like `<base href="http://www.mydomain.com/">`.  That way, *all* relative URLs in your HTML will be interpreted as relative to the root of your site.
3. You *could* also fix the issue with more rewrite rules, something like:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^profile/((css|images|js)/.*) $1 [L]
   ```

   This is less efficient than the first two solutions, however, since the browser won't realize that the different URLs actually refer to the same style sheet (and even if you use an external rewrite to tell it that they do, it still needs to query the server to find out).

Comment: Ok thanx, but the first way didn't work so i use an alternative links :D