# rewrite showing only text without pictures and external javascript

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have code below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mozilla|navigator|chrome) [NC]
RewriteRule ^newfolder/(.*)$ /index.html [L,NC]
```

Problem is because it rewrite everything to index.html - it means that picture and external JavaScript won't be seen (loaded)... It only rewrite index.html (text) but other stuff from index not (picture, external JavaScript).
With [L,NC,R] work but whith [L,NC] not and I don't want visitors to see that is other page.
I want to show visitor full index.html with all it's content - but it is not showing pictures, external JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stylesheets break when rewriting a URL like profile/foo to profile.php?username=foo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030151/stylesheets-break-when-rewriting-a-url-like-profile-foo-to-profile-phpusername)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to 2 `RewriteCond` lines to exclude files and directories from this rewrite:

```
# fixed css/js/images
RewriteRule ^newfolder/((?!index).+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js|html?))$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mozilla|navigator|chrome) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^newfolder/(.*)$ /index.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: No, it's not working. It's not showing text from index.html and also not showing picture from index.html and javascript external related to index.html .... It do nothing as it seems - there is no error but it doesn't show nothing from index.html...

Comment: What are those JS or CSS URLs can you tell me some examples? Are you getting 404 for them (check in FIrebug)

Comment: Not showing can mean many things. You need to provide more info as I requested in my previous comment.

Comment: <img src="2.jpg" alt="ggggg" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="lepojs.js"></script>  this is in the code for example but it simply not loaded there are no error report what so ever... I think that in some way they are not request to be presented...

Comment: Ok got it, can you change it to absolute links like: `<img src="/2.jpg" alt="ggggg" /> <script type="text/javascript" src="/lepojs.js"></script>`

Comment: Or else you can try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: It works now. It have to be add / to everything in index.html in order to work. i try with classic link and works just need / infront of it. It is a bit confusing changing it all in real page I must try that part with "base" should i put it below metakeywords, metadescription? I put your answer as correct.

Comment: You have some other alternate, ideas also? For thinking.

Comment: I try using <base href="/" /> below metawords not working. Anyway it works now it is not so problem I'm just curious..

Comment: Ok thanks. I try it later I must go. I will try it later and put here what I came up with. You have been very helpful. Thank you once again.

Comment: It does work now for all above listed except for .html links but I guess it is not possible because of last rewriterule. But with / added to everything in index it will work fine. Thank you once again. You have been very helpful. Regards.

Comment: You're welcome, edited the answer to take care of `.html` links also.

Comment: .html won't work as it should. With those update you pute it do redirect from mywebsite.com/newfolder/somefile.html into mywebsite.com/index.html it do job but it show in address bar redirection not just [L] - mywebsite.com/newfolder/somefile.html ...

Comment: URL change happens due to `R=301`. Try removing that test in a new browser?

Comment: Can you look in this new question I put a link here, just follow it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704271/htaccess-file-all-others-whoa-re-not-some-browser

Comment: I HAVE ONE MORE QUESTION LINK is folloving: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725692/using-rewritecond-with-rewriterule

Comment: I hope you are still connect to this page. I put here another link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984945/time-lock-for-rmod-rewrite-in-htaccess-file

Comment: Ok sure let me check.