# Using rewritecond with rewriterule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I em interesting will It be better as I put:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(safa|navigator) [NC]
RewriteRule ^drugi/(.*)$ /index.html [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^treci/(.*)$ /index.html [L,NC]
```

Or I have to put RewriteCond for each RewriteRule separate like below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(safa|navigator) [NC]
RewriteRule ^drugi/(.*)$ /index.html [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(safa|navigator) [NC]    
RewriteRule ^treci/(.*)$ /index.html [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to the very next `RewriteRule` therefore your first code is not right. But there is better way to combine those 2 rules into one using regex `|`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(safa|navigator) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(drugi|treci)/(.*)$ /index.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: You are fast. It works, it is the best solution. I put here a link for another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734474/htaccess-using-escape-quotes

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out, I will check other question also.