# .htaccess using escape quotes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(aa.bbb|aaa,bbb|aaa-bbb|aaa_bbb||)/(.*)$ /index.html [L,NC]
```

Will it be fine as above or should it be with espae quotes. I know in javascript is often \ in use. Like below:

```
RewriteRule ^(aa\.bbb|aaa,bbb|aaa-bbb|aaa_bbb)/(.*)$ /index.html [L,NC]
```

I need it for   - _ , .  all four of them. Do I need \ or some other sign in .htaccess and what is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- From your rules only dot needs to be escaped (since that is special regex character)
- Two `||` should be removed otherwise that can match empty string
- You can use character class to greatly reduce your regex
- Inside character class none of these character need to be escaped.

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(aa[.,_-]bbb)/(.*)$ /index.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: So in basic all I need is (aa\.bbb|aaa,bbb|aaa-bbb|aaa_bbb) or (aa[.,_-]bbb)